# In Python how to name columns in pandas data frame so that one column is string and the others are numbers in range?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have data with column names, say a-g, I would like to name for instance first column "Something" and the others with name as integers in range for instance 1000-1005.

I know how to do range of integers as names with

```
df.columns=[str(i) for i in range(1000, 1006)]
```

but I am unable to combine it with the String.

Comment: df.columns= ["Something"] + [str(i) for i in range(1000, 1006)]

Comment: Thanks! Pretty embarassing, It is probably the only thing I have not tried, I have tried with lists and all kind of stuff. I must learn to think more in terms of "Occam's razor".